# Define a 2-input bell-shape function.

Tags: geometry, functions

I would like to define a function $z = f(x,y)$ on a surface, which more or less looks like:

[image]

The blue area is where the function has non-zero output. The blue color intensity shows the output value, i.e. $z_\textrm{max} = f(X_0, 0<y< Y_0)$. Also, the farther $x$ from $X_0$ is, the smaller $z$ becomes.
As a simple example, the envelopes of the blue area can be approximated to the inverse of normal distribution function, i.e.
$$y(x) = Y_0 \left(1 - e^{-\pi Y_0^2 \left({x-X_0 }\right)^{2}} \right).$$
However, this in general does not hold true. Therefore, I would also like to generalize $y(x)$ as much as possible, such that the width of the envelope at any given $y$, can be modified arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve this problem and obtain $z = f(x,y)$, we need two other functions. The first function is
$$y_r(x) = Y_0 \left(1 - e^{-\pi Y_0^2 \frac{\left(x-X_0\right)^{2}}{r^2}} \right),$$
which determines the blue area boundaries.
As we know the envelopes, we can define a step function whose output is 1 in the blue area and 0 elsewhere.
$$g(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-100\left(y-y_r(x)\right)}}$$
The following figure is $g(x,y)$, for $X_0 = 1$ and $Y_0 = 2$.
[image]

Given that the values of z decrease gradually away from $X_0$, we can use normal distribution function to relate $x$ and $z$ as
$$f(x,y) = g(x,y)\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}e^{-{\frac {1}{2}}\left({\frac {x-X_0 }{\sigma }}\right)^{2}} $$
In the following picture $\sigma = 0.4$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there.
Define

$$u(x) = Y_0 \left(1 - e^{-\pi Y_0^2 {x}^{2}} \right).$$

Then define
$$
y_{r, a}(x) = u\left(\frac{x-a}{r}\right)
$$
Then $y_{r,a}$ will be centered at $x = a$, and the "blue area' will be $r$ times as wide as your original function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
How about the other function $z = f(x,y)$?

Comment: To be honest, your description of $z$ makes no sense to me, so I didn't try to generalize it. Sorry!